# Mongodb: sort by elements in an array

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am working on a project and I found a request that I don't understand and is not working. We have documents that look like this:

```
 {
        "id": ObjectId("6457959757555445"),
        "buyer" : { 
            "id": ObjectId("588888815654684")      
            "roles" : [ 
                "BUYER"
            ]
        }
},
{
        "id": ObjectId("6457959707555445"),
        "buyer" : { 
            "id": ObjectId("588800015654684")      
            "roles" : [ 
                "ADMIN"
            ]
        }
}
```

And there is a request that should sort a collection of theses documents by roles. So for the example above, I will have `ADMIN` then `BUYER`. So here is the request:

```
{  
   "aggregate":"__collection__",
   "pipeline":[  
      {  
         "$sort":{  
            "buyer.roles":1
         }
    },
}
```

Should we really use `pipeline` here? and why it is not working?

Comment: Hi.Can you explain better what you want to obtain? roles is an array. How to sort something by an array?

Comment: Hi. Yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: Do you need to sort with role name that is "ADMIN" will come first and "BUYER" will second?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Yes exactly

Comment: So what if            "roles" : [ 
                "ADMIN", "BUYER"
            ]
?

Comment: Actually roles always contains one element.

Comment: Ok, so you should order by the first element of the array

Comment: Both  `db.colname.find().sort({"buyer.roles.0": 1})` and   `db.colname.find().sort({"buyer.roles": 1})` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) "roles" array and then you can easily apply [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on "roles"

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$buyer.roles"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "buyer.roles": 1
    }
  }
])
```